# Are 'link tables' in postgresql supposed to automatically update when records are added to primary tables?

Tags: postgresql, foreign-keys, many-to-many

Noob question - Basically I'm trying to get a link table for a many-to-many relationship to auto update. I don't really know if this is what is supposed to happen, but I don't think I'm supposed to manually copy data into it either.

Below is my DDL - if `glo.link_table` is made this way, and I add data to both `glo.collectors` and `glo.natural_hazards`, shouldn't `glo.link_table` auto-update? Right now `glo.link_table` is not doing anything when I copy data into to `glo.collectors` and `glo.natural_hazards`. I'm guess I'm expecting `glo.link_table` to like add records when I add data to those two tables.

```
    --Drop if exsits & create
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS  glo.collectors CASCADE;
 
-- Make collectors table
CREATE TABLE glo.collectors (
  u_id serial,
  user_name text NOT NULL,
  password text NOT NULL,
  email text NOT NULL,
  agency text NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (u_id)
);
 
--Drop if exsits & create
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS glo.natural_hazards;
 
-- Create natural hazards table
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS glo.natural_hazards(
      nathaz_id SERIAL,
      data_version text, 
      data_class text, -- class = foundational  
      agency text NOT NULL,
      data_owner text,
      data_url text NOT NULL,
      keywords text,
      spatial_ref text,
      creation_date text,
      data_description text,
      data_purpose text, 
      fema_sfha text,
      event_inundation text,
      video_catalog text,
      hazard_scale text,
      PRIMARY KEY (nathaz_id)
);
 
--Drop if exsits & create
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS glo.link_table;
 
-- Create link table
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS glo.link_table(
      u_id int REFERENCES glo.collectors (u_id) ON UPDATE CASCADE ON DELETE CASCADE,
      nathaz_id int REFERENCES glo.natural_hazards (nathaz_id) ON UPDATE CASCADE,
      CONSTRAINT link_table_pkey PRIMARY KEY (u_id, nathaz_id) 
      );
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No the link_table will not auto populate. Those columns will act in a similar way to a 'foreign key' and ensure that there is some form of constraint on what can be inserted into these columns.

Data that already exists in the link_table will be affected by changes to data in the tables that these columns reference. But this data will have to be inserted separately.

[column references documentation](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/ddl-constraints.html)

For automatically inserting data into the link_table I would suggest possibly using a trigger.

[Trigger documentation](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-createtrigger.html)